# Using Clang Thread Safety Analysis with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, thread-safety, clang, shared-ptr

I'm looking at the [Clang Thread Safety Analysis](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html)  feature with Clang 7.0

However, I'm getting an error when I attempt to use the PT_GUARDED_BY annotation with `shared_ptr` data members:

> error: 'pt_guarded_by' only applies to pointer types; type here is 'shared_ptr<MyClassType>' [-Werror,-Wthread-safety-attributes]

This is a bit confusing to me, as the documentation says "PT_GUARDED_BY is ... intended for use on pointers and smart pointers.", and even gives an example which uses std::unique_ptr (using basically the same syntax I'm using).

Is std::shared_ptr incompatible with Clang's thread safety analysis, or is there something else going on here? How should I be stating that the pointed-to class shouldn't be accessed without holding a lock on the associated mutex?

(This is on Linux using GCC's libstdc++ standard library, if it matters.)

---

After some experiments, it looks like this only happens if the shared_ptr is a member variable, not a global.

```
#include "mutex.h" // The suggested mutex.h file from the Clang Thread Safety Analysis page
#include <memory>

Mutex mu;

std::shared_ptr< int > toplevel PT_GUARDED_BY(mu); // Okay

class Wrapper {
public:
  std::shared_ptr< int > member PT_GUARDED_BY(mu); // Results in error
};

void test() {
  Wrapper wrapped;
  wrapped.member = std::shared_ptr< int >( new int ); // Should be OK
  *wrapped.member = 42; // Should raise warning
}
```

I'll note that if I swap out `unique_ptr` for the `shared_ptr` both the global and the member variable work fine.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Not really related, except on the superficial "both are about shared_ptr and threads" level. My question isn't concerned with efficiency of shared_ptr, or even the intrinsic thread safety guarantees of the shared_ptr class. Instead, it's about the use of shared_ptr with a particular static analysis tool (which happens to be checking thread safety issues).

Comment: Reading the docs, it should indeed work. However I do know that libc++ has extra annotations related to it's tools. Have you tried that one instead?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit with various compilations of Clang and different C++ standard libraries, I think I have this figured out.

It's a bug in Clang 7.0.0 when used in conjunction with (GCC's) libstdc++.

If you use current (4 Dec 2018) trunk Clang (so what will become 8.0.0 eventually) things work as expected with both (GCC's) libstdc++ and (Clang's) libc++.

If you use Clang 7.0.0, things work as expected with (Clang trunk's) libc++, but raises the above error if you use it with (GCC's) libstdc++ ... at least for libstdc++ from the GCC 4.8 - GCC 6.2 range (which is what I had on hand to test.).